# The relationship of overload and method return type in Java?

Tags: java, methods, overloading, return-type

If there are two methods, they have different parameters, and their return types are **different**. Like this:

```
int test(int p) {
   System.out.println("version one");
   return p;
}

boolean test(boolean p, int q) {
   System.out.println("version two");
   return p;
}
```

If the return types are same, of course this is **overload**. But since the return types are *different*, can we regard this as **overload** still?

Comment: Yes. When overloading, the only thing that matters is the name of the method.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel And that the number/type of parameters are different (and incompatible).

Comment: @biziclop: that's what distinguishes overloads from eachother. But it's just the name that determines they are overloads in the first place.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel What I tried to say is that you can't have two methods with the same name and parameters but different return types. That's not overloading but a compile error. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

consider following points for overloading:

1. First and important rule to overload a method in java is to change method signature. Method signature is made of number of arguments, type of arguments and order of arguments if they are of different types.

   ```
   public class DemoClass {
       // Overloaded method
       public Integer sum(Integer a, Integer b) {
           return a + b;
       }

       // Overloading method
       public Integer sum(Float a, Integer b) {  //Valid
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Return type of method is never part of method signature, so only changing the return type of method does not amount to method overloading.

   ```
   public class DemoClass {
       // Overloaded method
       public Integer sum(Integer a, Integer b) {
           return a + b;
       }

       // Overloading method
       public Float sum(Integer a, Integer b) {     //Not valid; Compile time error
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Thrown exceptions from methods are also not considered when overloading a method. So your overloaded method throws the same exception, a different exception or it simply does no throw any exception; no effect at all on method loading.

   ```
   public class DemoClass {
       // Overloaded method
       public Integer sum(Integer a, Integer b) throws NullPointerException{
           return a + b;
       }

       // Overloading method
       public Integer sum(Integer a, Integer b) throws Exception{  //Not valid; Compile time error
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

To quote [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

> The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists (there are some qualifications to this that will be discussed in the lesson titled "Interfaces and Inheritance").

Having a different return type is inconsequential to overloading. In fact, this is quite common with methods that return one of their arguments. E.g., [`java.util.Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) has a bunch of overloaded `max` methods. A `max` of two `int`s return an `int`, a `max` of two `double`s return a `double`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is also an overload. Since only the name and the list of parameters are considered part of method's signature for the purposes of method overloading, both your `test` methods are overloads of each other.

There may be useful scenarios for overloading a method like that, too. Consider this example:

```
class Sanitizer {
    public static String sanitize(String s) {
        ...
    }
    public static int sanitize(int s) {
        ...
    }
    public static double sanitize(double s) {
        ...
    }
}
```

A programmer who uses `Sanitizer` can write things like

```
String s2 = Sanitizer.sanitize(s1);
int num2 = Sanitizer.sanitize(num1);
```

and the overload makes the code looks the same for variables of different types.

Answer (score 2):

In function overloading return types don't play any role.
Function overloading can only be achieved via change in arguments.
So, yes in your given case test() is overloaded