# does overloading work with inheritance in java? explain this concept

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

Mainly i want to know concept behind it.

```
public class Myprogram3 {

  public static void main(String args[]){
    Derived obj = new Derived();
    System.out.println(obj.f(3));
    System.out.println(obj.f(3.3));
  }
}
class Base{

    public int f(int i){
        System.out.print("f (int): ");
        return i+3;
    }
}
class Derived extends Base{
    public double f(double i){
        System.out.print("f (double) : ");
        return i + 3.3;
    }
}
```

### output:

```
f (int): 6
f (double) : 6.6
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: Look's like homework? What did you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The relationship of overload and method return type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892125/the-relationship-of-overload-and-method-return-type-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of overloading and inheritance are not really related.

You are defining the method `f` to take either a double or an int (overloading). The compiler decides which method to call based on the parameters.

You are inherting one of the overloaded methods from a base class (inheritance).

But you could equally put both methods in the same class and it would still work and you could rename one of your methods (so you don't have overloading) and it would still work.

They are separate concepts.